# Error using grass script v.lidar.edgedetection

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm in trouble with the grass script v.lidar.edgedetection. When I try to filter an xyz format dsm the script starts but at the end of it an error message appears (see attached image).

[image: Screen shoot of the error message]

Any idea where is the problem?

I tried to perform the same operation with a different file format (.las) but I have the same error.